# How to access string and object simultaneously inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

how to access the name of all city inside this array:

```
const arr = [
  "delhi",
  "chandigarh",
  "mumbai",
  { name: "naveen", city: "hyderabad" },
  { name: "michael john", city: "america" },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all `city` names in an array using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
arr.map((a) => (typeof a === "object" ? a.city : a)
```

and you can check its `type` using [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) because if it is an object then it will return `object`

```js
const arr = [
  "delhi",
  "chandigarh",
  "mumbai",
  { name: "naveen", city: "hyderabad" },
  { name: "michael john", city: "america" },
];

const result = arr.map((a) => (typeof a === "object" ? a.city : a));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: then we can also use forEach like arr.forEach((data) => (typeof data==="Object"?console.log(data.city):console.log(data)))

Comment: yes, But forEach doesn't return anything then if you want to store `city` let say in `array`, then you need to declare that `array` prior to `forEach`